# jQuery animate height with following content

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I am expanding a div with jQuery animate. However inside that div I have another div which I want to follow with the expansion and always be at the bottom to the right.

This is the jquery code

```
$( ".top-button" ).click(function() {
    $('.top-menu').animate({ height: 110 }, 800);
});
```

I am guessing it is something CSS related?

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U5Mjp/)

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/U5Mjp/

Comment: You don't have it positioned so it shows up in the bottom right corner.

Comment: Something like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/U5Mjp/6/

Comment: Why does it disappear while it expands? The black box?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$( ".top-button" ).click(function() {
    $('.top-menu').animate({height:110},800);
    $('.top-button').animate({bottom:0},800);
   });
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/U5Mjp/15/)

Comment: Hmm, I was trying to make it look like a tab as in the example. This code moves the tab to the inside of the div.